# How to recover from accidentally undoing work in Android Studio via git?

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I've  a project submission coming up. I committed my project on Android Studio then tried to push it to GitHub but got a warning about conflicts. I was on the master branch so not sure how it happened. Anyway I tried to pull back but it said revert was failing so I went back a step and now Im at a commit from about 2 weeks ago and unsure how to get my last 2 weeks of work back.

Im not fully clued up git commands, simply just been using the VSC interface provided by android studio. Any help much appreciated, I am panicking here

Comment: What is the output of `git status` on the command line?

Comment: If you committed, you can always check `git reflog` to see to what revision you might want to jump to.

Comment: #1 before to try any rescue command, zip your entire git repository!! .git folder stores everything.  #2 Did Tokrnike & AlanDeep answers help you?

Comment: Tornike got it bang on, thank the lord. Time to learn git and dont touch when I don't understand the implications

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all do not panic, android studio automatically saves local changes for some amount of time.

1. Switch to project view in android studio
2. Right-click on your project and click on Local History,
   now you can select changes before the action that broke your code and revert it, by double-clicking on local history items, IDE shows you differences of files between current and version you can revert to

Comment: You beauty! Got it!

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry. Your work is still there even if you can't see it.

```
git reflog
```

there you can see the list of commits you need.

Copy the list of commits to notepad or open another terminal, then start trying them using:

```
git checkout <hash>
```

once you find your desired commit, run the following:

```
git checkout master

git reset --hard <hash>
```

where  is the success commit hash you found.